# How to fix Broken label sd card mmcblk0?

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, data-recovery, gparted

I can't mount my 16gb sd card after my computer shut down will i was copping some file into the card , i tried to fix it using fdisk i think somehow i managed to delete the header of disk also

i traid adding table partition with gparted but it won't work

> Device -> New Partition Table.

I also try to recover the partition with [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) but it didn't fin anything with normal or deep scan

[image]

```
root@localhost:~# mkdosfs -F 32 -v /dev/mmcblk0
mkfs.fat 3.0.28 (2015-05-16)
/dev/mmcblk0 has 4 heads and 16 sectors per track,
hidden sectors 0x0000;
logical sector size is 512,
using 0xf8 media descriptor, with 31211520 sectors;
drive number 0x80;
filesystem has 2 32-bit FATs and 16 sectors per cluster.
FAT size is 15226 sectors, and provides 1948814 clusters.
There are 32 reserved sectors.
Volume ID is 4d768915, no volume label.
```

I'm not concerned about the data in it, i just want know how can i fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the wipe menu of mkusb to create a new partition table and file system. The standard is an MSDOS partition table and one partition with the FAT32 file system. See the following links,

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

[mkusb/wipe](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/wipe)

[image]

**Edit:**

According to your output from

```
mkdosfs -F 32 -v /dev/mmcblk0
```

the device is recognized as a mass storage device. Such a device works best, when there is at least one partition. But you tried to create a file system directly on the device (without a partition structure) like it used to be on floppy disks, and like is is in CD/DVD disks.

You can create a partition table with manual tools, for example *gparted*, but it is 'automatic' with *mkusb*. When gparted does not work, I suspect that there are some data, that confuses gparted, and mkusb overwrites those data with zeros (overwrites the first megabyte).

Comment: can you explain more !! , because it seem that it only work on my working drive or it didn't read the drive

Comment: According to your output from 'mkdosfs -F 32 -v /dev/mmcblk0' the device is recognized as a mass storage device. Such a device work best, when there is at least one partition. But you tried to create a file system directly on the device (without a partition structure) like it used to be on floppy disks, and like is is in CD/DVD disks. You can create a partition table with manual tools, for example *gparted*, but it is 'automatic' with *mkusb*. When gparted does not work, I suspect that there are some data, that confuses gparted, and mkusb overwrites those data with zeros.

Comment: I edited the answer. I hope it helps. If not, please ask a specific question.